# Hide Model Property from Django admin and set Its Value Manually

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want to hide a column from django admin and set its value from session.

In simple words i want to set a property of a model from session and don't want a field in admin for that column.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [mark the field as read-only](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#editable) but still have it visible in the admin, or [completely exclude it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/).

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=20) # this is editable
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=20, editable=False) # this is not
```

or

```
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ['field2']
```

If you're using a custom model form in the admin, just [don't include the field in the `fields` attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/).

Comment: This does not explain how to set the value for the read_only/excluded value

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember there are a lot of ways to do this, with the fields attribute on `Meta` you can hide or select which fields to show.

check [This example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#a-full-example)